# Python-spawned subprocess jpgs in new window and exit on completion

Tags: python, window, subprocess, ubuntu

I have a file containing thus far some 1800 jpegs (it will grow) which I have to search manually for specific features. This requires that I enter a code (1 or 0) to say whether or not the features that I am looking for exist.

Because the features are difficult to define, the images of low quality and as far as we are aware no non-deterministic approach exists to deal with this satisfactorily it has to be coded.

The idea is to open the large_file containing the jpegs, open each of them in a new window one-by-one (so that I can see them), read in data from the screen and then close the new window.

Roughly this looks something like this:

```
large_file = open (xxxxxx, rb)                    # contains info identifying jpeg
for jpeg in large_file:                           # 1800 items now more later
open jpeg in separate window
  does image meet the criterion?:                 # Enter 1 or 0 (say) at console 
   if (1 or 0):
     close window and move to next image
   else:
     go back and ask for sensible input
large_file.close()
```

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 with lightdm as the display manager and Python 2.7.6. Browsing Stackoverflow doesn't really get me what I need.

Implementing using Image cause problems because I am not using xv, but lightdm. Several strategies have not worked properly. Clearly the core issue is spawning the new window and then closing it.

Any suggestions? In an ideal world I would prefer not to have to close images manually...

Many thanks

Comment: You could take a look at `pygame` - `img = pygame.image.load(image_path)` and then `screen.blit(img, (xpos, ypos))`. If you really want to get fancy, you can even capture mouse input, so a left click on image gives you a "1" and a right click a "0", eg. Save you from having to alt-tab back to the console every time there's a new image, I guess.

Comment: Are these jpegs all actually contained in a single file, or are they separate files contained in a single directory?

Comment: The file contains the IDs of the jpegs and some other info. They themselves are contained in one or more directories whose names can be constructed easily from the data in the file.

Comment: @ a p does  pygame spawn a window as a subprocess? I think from reading your comment that it does, but I am not sure. Could you clarify.

Comment: You could create a simple GUI that shows you pictures one by one and accepts your input (1/0). Look at a [simple slideshow implemented using Tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c). To install dependencies, run `sudo apt-get install python-{tk,pillow,imaging-tk}`. It shows how to display an image, how to accept input from keyboard, how switch images on event e.g., on key press.